# Is there a 'word' for a class method type or how can I save it?

Tags: c++

For the class itself,  I know that `this`  can be used.

But what about the class method ?

I use https://blog.coldflake.com/posts/C++-delegates-on-steroids/  to create:

```
class A
{
...
    Delegate<int, char> d = DELEGATE(&A::foo, this);
... int foo (char a) {return 0;}
};
```

I want to wrap `DELAGATE` so I can do:

1. Set the `DELEGATE`'s callee (`this`) and method type ( `word?` ) for the entire class in advance.

   e.g.,:

   `WRAP_DELEGATE MyDelegate.Init(this, word?>`
2. Set the DELEGAE function.

   e.g.,:

   `MyDelegate.Set(foo);`

How can I achieve it?

Could not find a similar example to what I need.

Comment: Can you give a short explanation and/or implementation of `DELEGATE` in the question, so we don't have to read a whole blog post to understand your question? Also, what is the reason to use this `DELEGATE` here instead of simply `std::function` or maybe even just a lambda?

Comment: There is no keyword naming the current function or current class by the way. So that would be the straight-forward answer to your question, but I want to understand what the actual problem you are trying to solve is. I also don't understand what you are trying to do with your points 1. and 2. A usage example would be helpful.

Comment: once you have class A then you know that class A won't do anything useful, and will just demonstrate syntax, although not in this instance.. i have never  felt te need for delegates in my own code, else i would have used them. just because you can think something up, doesn't mean you should use it. people that inherit your code wll thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Again, its pretty unclear what you asking for.
If you are asking in your first point about function "signature", i.e. return type and argument types, then you can use signatiures which is used in `std::function` and define it with `using` keyword, though you will need to expand `Delegate` template a little bit for it to parse such signatures and pass it to ususal `Delegate` implementation.

Some example:

```
// Adding Delegate signature wrapper
template<typename R, typename... Args>
class Delegate<R(Args...)> : public Delegate<R, Args...> {};

using foo_type = int(char);
Delegate<foo_type> d = DELEGATE(&A::foo, this);
```

But, its still impossible to set such signature just for any delegate **after** its initialisation. I.e. its impossible to implement **function** `Init` which will change type of existing `Delegate` variable. But its possible to create **macro** which will create `Delegate` of proper type.

As for second point, it is really easy to add to `Delegate` implementation. Just assing `fpCallbackFunction` to passed value and that's it.

```
class Delegate
{
...
  void Set(Type fun) {
    fpCallbackFunction = fun;
  }
...
};
```